# Can't redirect users to log in page when attempting to access a members only page

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I feel like I'm beating a dead horse by asking this question, but I'm just not understanding redirects... If a user attempts to access a members only web page without logging in, how do I redirect that user to the log in page? In my searching, I've seen several references to modifying my web.config file, however, nothing has stood out to me as being the key to getting this working... When I try to access a members only page when I'm not authenticated, I get a 404 error. When I am authenticated, the page loads just fine... What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LOTOConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=WIWRMS-SQLD2\SQLD2;Initial Catalog=LOTO;User ID=LOTO_ADMIN;Password=lotoadmin"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" >
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add
          name="SqlProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="LOTOConnectionString"
          applicationName="/"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true"
          passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <pages enableEventValidation="false" />
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was on the right track. All I needed to do was modify the authentication module from:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

to:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

The simple mistakes get me every time.